# Java Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I have a java project in eclipse that used to run normally, but now is throwing this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Program

However, if I copy-paste the project in eclipse, the copy runs normally. I'm curious about the possible reasons why the original project does not run. I checked some old posts about this topic but they were not helpful or I did not understand them. Can somebody help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you checked the JDK environmental paths in Windows and your IDE? Maybe they are not right.

Comment: If it is a Java project in Eclipse, Eclipse tells you what is wrong in the _Problems_ view. `C:\Program` is not a valid class name. So please show your run configuration.